# Z or t test for proportions from categorical variable in surveys

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I work with surveys (unweighted data) and my research vendor and I are debating what test to use when comparing whether two proportions are equal. What I mean is that we have a lot of data using a Likert scale (5 points agree) or binary data (yes/no).

While I would think to use a t-test with the formula to compare **means** (grouping ratings 4 and 5 together versus 1,2,3 for example)

$(\mu_1-\mu_2)/\sqrt(se_1^2+se_2^2)$

the vendor has argued that we should use something like a Z score with pooled variance. But, this seems to be the proper approach when one has dichotomous data and knows the standard deviation of the population.

So I guess my question is, when comparing proportions from survey data to see if they are significantly different, what test should I use?

Comment: Use the t score if you do not know the population standard deviation.